# 'Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)' type mismatch error Nº 13 in SQL/VBA code

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, adodb, oraoledb

I'm trying to export data from an Oracle Database through VBA, and I'm getting an error Nº 13 Type Mismatch at line:

```
mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
```

below is my entire code

```
Sub start()

Dim cn              As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs              As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mtxData         As Variant
Dim strSQL          As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.Open ( _
    "user ID =user" & _
    ";Password=password" & _
    ";data source=source" & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.oracle")
    
    rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    strSQL = ("SELECT * FROM table")
    rs.Open strSQL, cn
    mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
        
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K22") = mtxData
```

below is the result I was expecting...
[image]

Comment: Is your SQL-statement returning anything? Split the command into two lines: `mtxData = rs.GetRows : mtxData = Application.Transpose(mtxData)` and check the content of `mtxData` when the error occurs

Comment: Hi @FunThomas, just checked and my sql statement does return something, I used the line "MsgBox "max records found: " & rs.RecordCount" and it returned the number 21, which is exactly the number of rows inside the table.

I also tried the splitting suggestion into two lines, but the same problem occur when the code reachs the Application.transpose, could this error be occurring due to somekind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a type mismatch error from `Transpose` if the data you received via `GetRows` contains any null values.

There is, however, a better way to dump the data you have in a RecordSet into Excel: Simply use the method `Range.CopyFromRecordSet`. Advantage is you don't need the transpose, and you need to specify only the start cell.

```
Const connStr = "(Your connection String)"
Const sql = "(Your SQL)"

Dim cn              As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs              As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open connStr
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

With ActiveSheet
    .UsedRange.Clear
    .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

If you need also the column names, try this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .UsedRange.Clear
    Dim destRange As Range, colIndex As Long
    Set destRange = .Range("A1")
    ' Write column names
    For colIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        destRange.Offset(0, colIndex) = rs(colIndex).Name
    Next colIndex
    ' Dump the data
    destRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

Comment: hi, the second code that extract the column names works very well... but I think I'm missing something here, with the recordset I can get the data that I need, but it seems like I still need the transpose method, what am I missing here?

Thank you btw

Comment: The `CopyFromRecordset`-method writes the data directly to the sheet, no transpose needed.